# R-programming issue with ImageMagick

Tags: r, imagemagick

I am trying to create an animation using R and ImageMagicks.

Here is my simple code that just plots 5 different values of x,y and z on a 3dscatterplot.

```
simulator=function()
{
  library(scatterplot3d)
  for(i in 1:5)
  {
  png(paste(i,'plot.png',sep=''))
  scatterplot3d(i*10,i*10,i*10,
                main="Quadcopter Simulator",
                xlab = "X-axis",
                ylab = "Y-axis",
                zlab = "Z-axis",
                xlim=c(0,100),
                ylim=c(0,100),
                zlim=c(0,100),
                box=FALSE)
  dev.off()
  }
}
```

After this I get 5 .png images in my working directory.

Then I have to manually open command prompt and type these commands:

1) cd C:/Users/.... (location where my .png's are)
2)convert *.png -delay 1000 -loop 0 animation.gif

This works and creates a .gif of my .png at the same location.

When I try to do the same with by including it in my R script by adding to the end:

system('C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe" -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif',intern = TRUE)

It says :

Error in system("C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe\" -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif",  : 
  'C:\Program' not found

I am in a dilemma as how to address this issue.

So to sum up my problem I just want to somehow run command prompt commands through my R-script. Can someone please help me with the same.

Thanks Alot Guys for your patience and time.

Comment: You may have to quote the space between "Program" and "Files"

Comment: No, you don't. Look at using the new `magick` package.